# How to pick consistent background color, PSD to CSS

Tags: css, psd

I want to convert this to HTML+CSS

The background seems to be consistently white but it is not.

When I slice the logo and the heading image out and colorpick the background color around the logo to code it into CSS

Such background color would not match with the background surrounding the heading image. and vice versa.

Using a repeated vertical strip of image as background is not an ideal option for optimization for email

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r7VR.jpg)

Comment: So, what have you done so far?

Comment: @caelan. still stuck right there and move on to other thing. But if you find a way, much much appreciated